# Take A Lot Of Time To Create Object From Database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm using C# and MySql trying to make a desktop application. MySql is on a server. The problem that I found is my application takes quite a while to load data from database to create object. Here is my logic. A user opens up inventory page, then the application will load all products' data from database creating object and show list of products. The application worked fine when I have less products. When I have many products in the database, the loading process takes a while. Any suggestion on logic? My logic is probably not good enough.

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Write better code. I can't tell you much more than that given your description

Comment: How are you loading data from database? Why you need to load all the products from database? Did you try getting paginated data?

Comment: I use one query to download needed data and create product object in "while (reader.Read())" loop. By the time the application finishes reading the data, I get all product objects.

Comment: share your logic

Comment: I up vote your problem , someone down voted yours i know how it feels when someone down vote your problem As if like no one understand you

Answer (score 1):

You should use paging to get limited data from database at most 25 then on next page 25, like this you can avoid overhead the problem of slowness